# Navigation bar becomes transparent when keyboard opened

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, landscape, navigationbar, android-immersive

Here is how it looks.
[image: transparent navigation bar]

And here are details.
I have activity without background. But it's not an issue. Neither setting background drawable or colour in theme or code fixed an issue.

Activity has soft input mode `adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden`

I also set those flags for activity's decor view in code

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

I tried explicitly set colour to navigation bar in theme like this

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/chat_bg</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
```

But had no success(

I can reproduce it only on my LG Nexus 5X. On other devices I tried navigation bar appears filled with color.

Comment: Since it only appears on one device, you might be looking at a firmware bug. Although the fact that it's a Nexus makes it very unlikely.

Comment: I tried Nexus 6P emulator and had same effect. Maybe it all nexus phones. Nexus 7 with android 6 has black nav bar at the bottom. Not transparent.

Comment: Well, but the Nexus phone have the "correct" implementation, so there must be something wrong with your code, but I'm afraid I cannot help you with that. EDIT: Or maybe it's intended funtionality. Unlikely though.

Comment: Even if it is correct I'd like to known how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem today. In my case this was because of the theme my Activity was using which was a theme derived from: `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`. The problem was not in custom theme but apparently the one from AppCompat library. When I changed the parent of my custom style to: `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` it started displaying with a solid black background color which is more desired than transparent. I agree this looks like a glitch.

I hope this will help someone in the future as I am aware that this is kind of a late answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution long ago. Maybe this will help you now

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
}
```